# Show Google Images Using Curl, PHP and HTML - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, curl

I know how we can use the Google API to return image results in AJAX, but I want to be able to return images for a specific query and then output them in to HTML using Curl and PHP on my page.

[This query](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=MYQUERY) is an example.

We want this to return in HTML so we can out put it on the page eg.:

```
<img src="<?php echo('googleimage'); ?>"/>
```

We are using this on Wordpress and we want MYQUERY to be the title of the page/post the user is on. Please help!

I've tried:

```
<?php
$posttit = get_the_title();
function get_url_contents($url) {
$crl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT        5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

$ret = curl_exec($crl);
curl_close($crl);
return $ret;
}

$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q='.$posttit);

$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->responseData->results as $result) {
$results[] = array('url' => $result->url, 'alt' => $result->title);
}

?>

<?php foreach($results as $image): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: ...And...what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?  v=1.0&q=.$tit.');
```

Which should read:

```
$json = get_url_contents('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q='.$tit);
```

However, your `$tit` variable (you are strongly recommended to not hog 3-chars-or-less variable names. The more expressive they are, the easier code is to maintain) is not accessible within the scope of the `function`. You can pass it as a parameter, or you can use `global $tit;` inside the function to hoist it inside your scope.

The second option, while "it works"-worthy, is very strongly recommended **against**, as it forces you to pollute the global namespace to use your function, and could lead to a lot of chaos in case you ever decide to use `curl_multi` (multi is asynchronous).

Comment: Hi sebastien, the problem is, that gives me the following error:    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/movies/public_html/wp-content/themes/moviestv/single.php on line 85

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/movies/public_html/wp-content/themes/moviestv/single.php on line 91

Comment: @AlanCarr: then the return of the API wasn't valid json. simple as that. Can you edit your question with your new code or var_dump the return of curl?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thanks for all your help with this. I've updated the code I'm using in the main question